# How can I get all the fields that have the same name in an object in django at views.py?

Tags: python, django-views

I have tried this and it never worked. The problem is that I have more than one field with the same name I am using to search. It's returning 'get() returned more than one object -it returned 2.

At views.py:

```
refer = Direct.objects.get(username=username)
```

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific - give a **code example** of what exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a class in which i have four fields.One field can have more than one value with the same name.How can i get all the values with the same name at that field in that class.As in when i try.Object.objects.get(value=value).it returns a multivalue error key because the they are more than one